# Existential quantifier distribution over imply

Tags: logic

$$\Big(\exists x \in X, (p(x) \rightarrow q(x))\Big) \iff \Big((\exists x \in X, p(x)) \rightarrow (\exists x \in X, q(x))\Big)$$

How do I prove this is wrong using examples (not law)

Comment: Try $X=\{1,2\}$, $p(x)\equiv x=1$, $q(x)\equiv \perp$

Comment: In addition to Hagen's comment and Henning's answer, you can also reflect on a couple of equivalences: (1) implication translates into negation and disjunction as follows: $A\to B \equiv \neg A \lor B$; (2) negation moves across quantifiers in a way that's a sort of "infinitary de Morgan's law": $\neg\exists \equiv \forall\neg$.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find **either** a structure where $\exists x(p(x)\to q(x))$ is true and $(\exists x\,p(x))\to(\exists x\,q(x))$ is false, **or** the other way around.

It is very difficult to make $\exists x(p(x)\to q(x))$ false -- that would require *every* $x$ to satisfy $p(x)$ but not $q(x)$, which would make the RHS false too.

So we need to make $\exists x(p(x)\to q(x))$ *true* instead. We can do that without disturbing the quantifiers on the right, simply by having one $x$ where neither $p(x)$ nor $q(x)$ hold.

Then, however, $(\exists x\,p(x))\to(\exists x\,q(x))$ must be false, and the only way to do that is for $\exists x\,p(x)$ to be *true* and $\exists x\,q(x)$ *false* ...

Can you complete the construction of a counterexample from here?

Comment: I can't find any examples that makes )∃xp(x)  to be true and ∃xq(x) false

Comment: @Cup: Are you sure? Try to express in words what it means for $\exists x\,p(x)$ to be true and for $\exists x\,q(x)$ to be false -- that will practically tell you exactly what your counterexample needs to be.